# How to block users in my app (swift + parse)

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am building an app using parse where users can click in annotation in a map and see a picture of that place.
My problem is with the block button ... It does not work, when the user click on the block button, he should not see any annotation by the user he is blocking but that unfortunately does not work .

Here is my block button :

```
@IBAction func blocking(_ sender: Any) {
    let block = PFObject(className: "blocking")

    block["me"] = PFUser.current()?.username
    block["poster"] = post?.name
    block["posterID"] = post?.id

    block.saveInBackground { (succ, error) in
        if error != nil {

            print("rttot")
        } else {

            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "mo", sender: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

(note the poster ID is the ID of person who post the the picture and poster is the name of the person who made the post)

This action will start a relationship between the the user and the user who is blocking . now I will not show any post that hold the person I am blocking ID .

```
    let queryy = PFQuery(className: "blocking")
    queryy.whereKey("me", equalTo: PFUser.current()?.username)
    queryy.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) in
        if error != nil {

            print("error")

        } else {



            for object in objects! {
                if let neww = object.object(forKey: "posterID") {


     var query = PFQuery(className: "posts")
     query.whereKey("id", notEqualTo: neww)
      query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) in
         if error != nil {

            print("error")

           } else {



              for object in objects! {   

                   let post = Posts()

                   post.chosen = object.object(forKey: "chosen") as! String

                  post.lati = object.object(forKey: "lati") as! Double
                   post.longi = object.object(forKey: "longi") as! Double
                post.image = object.object(forKey: "image") as? PFFile
                    post.text = object.object(forKey: "text") as! String
                post.name = object.object(forKey: "name") as! String
                   post.uid = object.object(forKey: "uid") as! String
                 post.id = object.object(forKey: "id") as! String



                print("999")

                var cord = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: post.lati, longitude: post.longi)


                let anno = annoClass(cord: cord, post: post, text: "Destination", subText: "ClickMe")

                self.myMap.addAnnotation(anno)


            }



           }

     }
    }

                    }

                }

            }
```

As you can see it will take the ID of people I am blocking and not showing their posts in the map but that does not work . The app does not show any error or bug btw.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
    queryy.whereKey("User_has_Blooked", equalTo: false) // if its equal to true, it should not show the users. make this object in the same class when you fetch users in the map!
```